# Two Knockout computed dependent on each other

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have 3 fields:

- Net Price (ex. tax)
- tax amount
- Total price (price ex. vat + tax amount)

The `NetPrice` and the `Total` are writable (i.e. you can change either of them and the other 2 values must be auto-calculated).

The way I've done it is using 3 observable and 2 computed knockout objects but I thought perhaps someone who knows Knockout a lot better could suggest a more efficient way to achieve this.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/vFK82/)

HTML:

```
Net Price:
<input type="textbox" data-bind="value: NetPriceCalc" />
<br />Tax Amount:
<label data-bind="html: TaxAmt"></label>
<br />Total:
<input type="textbox" data-bind="value: TotalCalc" />
```

Script:

```
var viewModel = {
    NetPrice: ko.observable(100),
    TaxAmt: ko.observable(20),
    Total: ko.observable(120),
    TaxRate: 0.2
};

viewModel.updateTaxAmt = function (useNetPrice) {
    if (useNetPrice) {
        return this.TaxAmt(this.NetPrice() * this.TaxRate);
    } else {
        var total = Number(this.Total());
        var taxAmt = total - total / (1 + this.TaxRate);
        return this.TaxAmt(taxAmt);
    }
};
viewModel.updateNetPrice = function () {
    this.NetPrice(Number(this.Total()) - Number(this.TaxAmt()));
};
viewModel.updateTotal = function () {
    this.Total(Number(this.NetPrice()) + Number(this.TaxAmt()));
};

viewModel.NetPriceCalc = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        console.log("NetPriceCalc read");
        return viewModel.NetPrice();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        console.log("NetPriceCalc write");
        viewModel.NetPrice(value);
        viewModel.updateTaxAmt(true);
        return viewModel.updateTotal();
    }
});
viewModel.TotalCalc = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        console.log("TotalCalc read");
        return viewModel.Total();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        console.log("TotalCalc write");
        viewModel.Total(value);
        viewModel.updateTaxAmt(false);
        return viewModel.updateNetPrice();
    }
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Just in any case anybody also didn't knew knockout like me: http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: I answered your question on stackoverflow, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920306/circular-dependency-of-knockout-computed/15924786#15924786

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will review and contrast the SO answer that I liked best:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.NetPrice = ko.observable(100);

    self.TaxRate = 0.2;

    self.TaxAmt = ko.computed(function() {
        return parseFloat(self.NetPrice()) * self.TaxRate;
    });

    self.Total = ko.computed({
        read: function() { 
               return parseFloat(self.NetPrice()) + self.TaxAmt();
        },
        write: function(val){
                var total = parseFloat(val);
                var taxAmt = total - total / (1 + self.TaxRate);     
                self.NetPrice(total - taxAmt);
        }
    });
}
```

- It is more standard to create a constructor, then to create an object with object notation and then add functions.
- Not to big a fan of using `self` everywhere instead of `this` in the SO answer
- Do not use `console.log` in production code
- Do not use `calc` as part of the variable name
- Do not use a `useNetPrice` type of indicator, knockout can figure out the `computed` values on its own and knows when to recalculate what
- `write` functions do not have to `return` anything